# Shortkey to turn on/ off x symmetry

Tags: modeling

Is there any Shortkey to turn on/ off x symmetry for modelling for both Meshes & Bones in edit mode?

Comment: You can assign a shortcut with the context menu. The shortcut works but there seems to be a bug and the switch is not updated to reflect its current state if you use the shortcut key. The correct state is shown when you hover the mouse over the switch (Blender 3.3)

Comment: The bug has been reported here: [T95251](https://developer.blender.org/T95251)